# Disable database connections with @SpringBootTest

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBoot application with hibernate. In my tests I would like to disable any sort of db connection and configuration (tests don't have access to db). How should I do it ?

My test class is annotated with `@SpringBootTest` and has `@Autowired` properties.
What's the proper annotation value to disable all db interactions ?

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {

  @Autowired
  ....
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue. have you found the solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@TestPropertySource` to override values in `application.properties`.

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
```

[A Quick Guide to @TestPropertySource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-test-property-source)

Comment: Spring data will be on spring context anyway, independent of your test property settings.

Comment: this don't solve the problem, your db beans are still use and they have no connection to db.